# Samba server not showing up in linux nor windows

Tags: samba, ubuntu-16.04

I've installed samba on a local server we have to share files across the network. It's started fine, but not showing up on the network at all. I can't even get to it by trying with the IP in linux nor windows.

I do not have a firewall setup on this server, and NFS is running fine with no issues.

Ubuntu 16.04.5

Here is my config.

```
[global]
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    netbios name = myserver.local
    security = user
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    server role = standalone server
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY
    interfaces = 192.0.0.0/8
    pam password change = yes
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    map to guest = bad user
    unix password sync = yes
    os level = 20
    encrypt passwords = yes
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    dns proxy = no
    max log size = 1000
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    bind interfaces only = false
    syslog = 0
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    usershare allow guests = yes

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[shares]
    force group = me
    writeable = yes
    force user = me
    path = /home/me/shares
```

**Edit:**

`netstat -antp` does not show `smbd`.

`journalctl`

```
Oct 24 11:41:49 user systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
Oct 24 11:41:49 user smbd[28299]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Oct 24 11:41:49 user smbd[28299]: Warning: Fake start-stop-daemon called, doing nothing.
Oct 24 11:41:49 user smbd[28299]:    ...done.
Oct 24 11:41:49 user systemd[1]: Started LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
```

**EDIT2**

`smbclient -L localhost`

```
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Connection to localhost failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
```

**EDIT3**

`ls /sbin/start-stop-daemon*`

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon  /sbin/start-stop-daemon.REAL
```

**EDIT4**

`sudo apt install -f`

```
Error: Server version (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) does not match with the version of
the server (5.7.24) with which this program was built/distributed. You can
use --skip-version-check to skip this check.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 3
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I did not have any issues when originally installing samba, and I have installed other packages since then without issues, just samba.

Comment: Does `netstat -antp` show the `smbd` or similar service listening on a port? If not, is the service running without errors?  Try `journalctl -u smbd`. Additionally, is the SMB share accessible from the server itself? Can you map `smb://localhost/sharename`?

Comment: Edits added above.

Comment: Something is wrong with your system. The 'Warning: Fake start-stop-daemon called, doing nothing' means that samba is NOT started up. The failed connection from smbclient confirms this.

Comment: What does `ls /sbin/start-stop-daemon*` return?

Comment: didn't you have some error while installing? Try running `apt-get install -f` in case some packages aren't completely installed or configured.

Comment: Seems an old `mysql-server-5.7` install, but it won't let me get past it. MySQL server is working perfectly fine, it's up and no issues.

Comment: I have fixed the `mysql-server` problem, then reinstalled samba, still same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Ubuntu was installing wrong, for some reason it was linking the startup job to a fake startup script. The answer is to move it to the real script:

```
sudo mv /sbin/start-stop-daemon.REAL /sbin/start-stop-daemon
```

Credits here: https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/18709-Clean-install-of-3-0-80-CIFS-shares-not-visible/?postID=147109#post147109